# git rebase all occurrences

Tags: git, rebase

branches:

> - *master*
> - *feature*

master:
    commit: 'm1'

```
function add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

feature (based on 'm1' commit):
    commit: 'f1'

```
function add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
+ function mult(a, b){
+   return a * b;
+ }
+ let a = 5, b = 2, c = 10;
+ const result = mult(add(a, b), c);
```

switch on master:
    commit: 'm2'

```
+ function addTo(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

After switching on feature, and typing 'git rebase master'
branch has commits (m1 - m2 - f1), and file changed like this:

```
function addTo(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
function mult(a, b){
    return a * b;
}
let a = 5, b = 2, c = 10;
const result = mult(add(a, b), c);
```

As you can see changed the name of function only at 1st line from '**add**' to '**addTo**', but
the name of same function '**add**' at last line hasn't changed to '**addTo**'. So code won't work correctly.
Is there a way to change function name at all accurences of code using '**rebase**' or smth like this?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no: rebase is not aware of *semantics* and cannot fix your code for you.

The longer answer is that if you have automated tests, you can use these automated tests to *check* each commit that rebase will make.  When these tests fail, a human can look at the failing commit.

Remember that rebase fundamentally works by copying some original series of commits to new and (supposedly) improved commits.  This is equivalent to using `git cherry-pick` one at a time on each ordinary (non-merge) commit (and merge commits are normally dropped entirely).  Meanwhile Git in general *finds* commits by using the fact that a *branch name* points to the *last* commit in that branch.  Each commit, regardless of however many branches contain it, points back to its parent commit(s), which forms a backwards-looking chain of commits; each commit in the chain can be copied.

So `git rebase` works—"changes" a branch—by:

1. Listing out commits to copy (their hash IDs).  This list ends with the commit that the branch name identifies.
2. Checking out a specific rebase target commit as a detached HEAD.
3. Using cherry-pick or equivalent to copy one commit at a time, from the list made in step 1.
4. Moving the branch name so that it identifies the final copied commit, and re-attaching HEAD.

When you run `git rebase` you can add `-x command` (or the longer spelling, `--exec command`) as an option.  This will run the chosen command after copying each commit.  If the chosen command reports success,<sup>1</sup> rebase moves on to the next commit as usual.  If it reports failure, the rebase stops itself at this point, returning control to the human.

The human should now investigate the failure and make any required corrections.  He/she/they/pronoun can run tests if/as needed, `git add` files and `git commit --amend`.  Once the problem is fixed, they can just `git rebase --continue` to move on to the next commit.

This `-x` trick works particularly well if you have a test suite that provides the right status.  In this particular case, the test could be as simple as running `make`, which typically provides the right status, although actual *tests* are a good idea.

(Not everyone tests every commit, and sometimes there is not enough time to do that, but the more tests you can cram in, the better, in most cases.)

---

<sup>1</sup>"Success" means `exit 0`; failure means the exit status was nonzero.  Well, unless perhaps you're on VMS, where exiting with either 0 or 1 from C code should report success, and only even numbers starting at 2 should report failure.